# Rails API - Devise: Update password on User update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm having a very weird issue with devise when trying to edit a user's password - here is a simplified version of what I'm doing at the moment:

```
def update

  user = User.find(params[:id])
  password              = params.delete(:password)
  password_confirmation = params.delete(:password_confirmation) 

  if password.present? and password != "" and password == password_confirmation
    user.password = password
  end

  user.update(params)
  user.save

  render json: user
end
```

What's really weird is that if I set password to an arbitrary string, by putting

```
 password = "testpassword"
```

above

```
 user.password = password
```

it works properly, the password is set to "testpassword", and i can log in using it just fine. But if I try and use the param like in the code above, I cannot log in using the password set in params[:password]. I have tried forcing the encoding of the string, and to use user.update_without_password, but to no avail.

Would anybody have any idea about this? it's driving me bonkers!

here is a dump of the params hash:

```
 {"username"=>"testytest", 
  "first_name"=>"Test",
  "last_name"=>"testy",
  "password"=>"password", 
  "password_confirmation"=>"password"}
```

To be a bit more precise, trying to login once this has been fired results in me not being able to login using the old password, or the new one. if there was a way to see which password gets saved in that function, I should be able to debug it!

Comment: What is the purpose of this code? Devise checks all conditions you write automatically.

Comment: well I've also tried to just use the password params in user.update, but to no avail. - the pb seems to be related to the format or encoding of the string containing the password param, but I don't see why! very weird stuff

Comment: please update a question with `params` hash you are receiving in this method. You can take it from logs, or use `raise params.inspect` as a first line in this method and submit the form. Still, I see no point in removing password from params then manually assigning in to password and firing 2 queries to database.

Comment: hey thanks for taking an interest in my question, it's appreciated! basically the code I have now is just something i tried, I basically tried a lot of various ways to set the password - the params basically look like this:   params[:password] = "password", params[:password_confirmation] = "password" ;  my core pb is that a string set in the code works, but not when it's coming from the params

Comment: I understood your issue, but can you print actual `params` you receive(it is important for debugging)? Just add `raise params.inspect` as a first line in update method, fill the form, submit it and copy-paste what was raised. Use edit question button to add this information.

Comment: done! as you can see i can't see anything different from the string in the params compared to one I would hardcode in the controller - super weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after 3 days of struggle I finally came up with a solution, however it's pretty ugly: what I did was this (I've added a method to the user model to simplify):

```
  def update_password(new_password)
    password_forced = ""
    new_password.each_byte do |byte|
       password_forced << byte.chr
    end
    self.password = password_forced
    self.save
  end
```

Again, inspecting the string coming from the params didn't point to anything that might be different from another ruby string... but anyway, this works!